# Rename tag [espresso]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-disambiguation

Please rename tag [espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/espresso) on Stack Overflow.

People constantly misuse it for questions related to a much more popular tag [android-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-espresso).

I suggest to rename tag [espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/espresso) to [macrabbit-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macrabbit-espresso). That way it will always be clear which one should be used.

Comment: Rename it? To be honest, why should we have a tag for a web editor? There isn't a [tag:DreamWeaver] tag, is there? Oh... there is. Jeez, that tag looks bad in use. So does this espresso tag (when used as a web editor). Is it bad to burn the [espresso]? Can we get off the [DreamWeaver] train? Or are IDE tags relevant? Turns out there are some use for them, such as when asking specifically about using the environment itself. However, not one of the espresso tagged questions does this. The entire set seems to be android-espresso based questions, so the tag can probably be made a synonym of that.

Comment: Judging from only the last pages ~10% of those questions are about MacRabbit Espresso

Comment: Based on usage the answer should be either to turn the tag into a synonym of android-expresso and move off the others.  @TravisJ we've decided questions on programming tools are on topic, so a tag is reasonable for macrabbit-espresso.  Although I agree they tend to be useless tags put on by people who don't understand the difference between a language, a platform, and an IDE more often than not.

Comment: Who is this [espresso] for?

Comment: So, what you're saying is that the tag for your [espresso] order got a bit messed up, resulting in you getting a double [espresso] when what you really should have is one [espresso] with a shot of `macrabbit-` and another [espresso] with a dash of `android-`?

Comment: "*`macrabbit-espresso`, what else?*" sounds really less good than "*`espresso`, what else?*"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From examining the entire set of 286 questions, there seem to be roughly 40 questions tagged with [espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/espresso) that are relating to the IDE. However, that leaves hundreds of others tagged with espresso for the wrong reason.

In a dozen or so the tag does seem to add context to the question, which means that just straight removing the tag would be counter productive in my opinion.

I agree that something should be done here, I would suggest this:

- create a new tag [macrabbit-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macrabbit-espresso) (done)
- replace [espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/espresso) with [macrabbit-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macrabbit-espresso) where relevant (done)
- synonymize [espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/espresso) with [android-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-espresso) (done)
- create a wiki page for [macrabbit-espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macrabbit-espresso)

Comment: [macrabbit-espresso] wouldn't be hard to find as it would probably be auto-suggested if you type `espresso`. I don't think `espresso-ide` is distinquished enough from `espresso` and `android-espresso`. There are a lot of amateur android developers who will still fall for the wrong tag.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. I will edit in the suggestion to use your macrabbit tag.

Comment: Awesome! sounds like a plan, lets do it!

Comment: So whats the next step? should we like mention a mod or something?

Comment: Well, given that this was only proposed 2 hours ago, you may want to wait a day or two to make sure anyone concerned can weigh in. From that point, seeing as how this is a rather small set of questions, you can create the proposed tag on your own, manually replace the incorrect espresso tags with the new tag, and then propose a tag synonym at this page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/espresso/synonyms from espresso to android-espresso

Comment: Fair enough. Will do that. Thank you for the answer and the advice!

Comment: It's been ~24 hours with just positive feedback. I think it safe to proceed with the changes.

Comment: Okay, go for it

Comment: The only last question is if we want [android-espresso] to be a synonym of [espresso] or the other way around? Started thinking about that since [android-espresso] already has one synonym... Any opinion?

Comment: android-espresso has *way* more posts tagged, so I would make espresso a synonym of android-espresso for that reason.

Comment: All [espresso] questions have been looked through yesterday and a new tag [macrabbit-espresso] has been created and applied where needed. Now the only last thing we need to do is to synonymize tags, which I cannot do because I don’t have enough score on this tag. @piotrek1543 would you mind making [espresso] a synonym of [android-espresso], as agreed above?

Comment: Just proposed the espresso as a synonym of android-espresso. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-espresso/synonyms

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti We need 2 more votes on that, this synonym currently has a score of 2

Comment: Completed as mentioned in this answer, after [asking an android user to check the posts once](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45308344#45308344). (cc @BartekLipinski)